# Undoing a branch merge

Tags: git

I just did `git pull origin branch` accidentally and now I have all these changes merged into `master`

I tried reverting the commit w/ github for mac and got this error:

```
fatal: Commit d0fbfb0f7d3ea8.. is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have not committed anything on top, `git reset --hard HEAD^` will do what you want. `HEAD^` refers to the first parent of the current commit, which is the one you want to reset back to.

A "hard reset" will set the current branch **and the work tree** to point to whatever you tell it to, discarding anything else (notably uncommitted changes). This is a **BIG** hammer, so be careful.

Comment: will `HEAD^` work? the branch i merged had multiple commits, so i need to go like 10 commits back to get to where i was before..

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

After a pull ( merge), ORIG_HEAD will point  to the previous HEAD.